# Nexus OSS Remote User Token (RUT) for SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, nexus

Hello I am using Nexus OSS, and wanted to simulate SSO, using Remote User Token. Currently the Nexus is configured to LDAP authentication, and is working fine.

As per the instructions found here https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/rutauth.html

Basically enabled Remote User Token and added header field Name "REMOTE_USER". This user is ldap and has access.

This instance is behind apache, so from apache, To test this RUT, I can set the header value REMOTE_USER, whoever, I don't see passed in user getting logged nor I see cookie being generated. I even tried firefox rest api client and set header, but with the same results. I can see that HTTP header is being set right.

Am I missing something?

Is there a way to debug that? Appreciate any help.

Thanks

S

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

RUT handles authentication, but the authenticated user still needs to be authorized to access the web UI.  What this means is that you need an LDAP user or group mapping in Nexus which assigns the necessary roles and privileges to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Nginx, the header was not set using the correct value.
This can be quite confusing, as the reverse proxy does not complain and simply sends a blank request header to Nexus.

Using Keycloak and Nginx (Lua), instead of a `preferred_username` field in the IdP response:

```
-- set headers with user info: this will overwrite any existing headers
-- but also scrub(!) them in case no value is provided in the token
ngx.req.set_header("X-Proxy-REMOTE-USER", res.preferred_username)
```

I had to use the `preferred_username` field returned in the response's `id_token` element:

```
-- set headers with user info: this will overwrite any existing headers
-- but also scrub(!) them in case no value is provided in the token
ngx.req.set_header("X-Proxy-REMOTE-USER", res.id_token.preferred_username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [patch for Nexus OSS with authorization via SSO and tokens](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso) instead of Remote User Token, more details in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75812912/19707292.