# How to create a Token in Nexus (for private packages) ? can't create a token through its UI

Tags: javascript, npm, devops, nexus, package.json

We're using **Sonatype Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.29.0-02** and we're trying to create a TOKEN
to work with `.npmrc` in the following structure :

```
registry=http://NEXUS-IP:8081/repository/GROUP-NAME
http://NEXUS-IP:8081/repository/GROUP-NAME/:_authToken=NpmToken.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

When I'm logged into the **Sonatype Nexus Repository ManagerOSS** I can't find anything that creates a valid token.

However , when I hit `npm login` from the command line and type the Username and Password ,
the `npm install` works.

How can we create a valid TOKEN for those Username/Password pair for the Nexus Artifactory ,
so I'll be able to use that token from a Docker ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that authenticating w/ AuthTokens (i.e. User Token Realm ) is only available in Nexus Pro :

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/user-authentication/security-setup-with-user-tokens

Answer (score 0):

[User tokens](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/user-authentication/security-setup-with-user-tokens) is available only in PRO version of Nexus (see [comparison](https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-oss-vs-pro-features)), but you can use "[Single sign-on patch for Nexus OSS](https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso)" which provides an alternative implementation of tokens without violating the license. The creation of tokens is implemented through the "NuGet API Key" menu, however, the tokens themselves apply to all types of repositories. Example of usage user token:

1. Run Nexus container from image "ghcr.io/a-langer/nexus-sso:3.46.0":

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/a-langer/nexus-sso.git
   cd ./nexus-sso
   docker compose up -d
   ```
2. Go to menu "Nexus -> Manage your user account -> NuGet API Key", press "Access API key".
3. Type your password or username if using SSO login, press "Authenticate".
4. Copy "Your NuGet API Key", press "Close" and "Sign out".
5. The received token can be used instead of a password in settings NPM, Docker, Maven and etc.

Each user can set a personal token that can be used instead of a password.